# Can't find app on CHPlay but can see it from URL and can find on browser

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app from some weeks ago and it actived and also have some thousands of user. I also released some versions for it.

But yesterday, I can't search my app on CHPlay from any device.However,  I still can find my app on browser in both of phone and laptop and also install it from this link.

I tried to find my app in some category of CHPlay. I still see my app but can't search it.

I also tried to release new version and it uploaded successfully :(

I don't understand why is it and what is causing this. Please tell me know what should I do in this case if you know.
Thanks.

Comment: Same thing happening with me as well!

Comment: what did u do in this case ?

Comment: Didn't find any solution yet!

Comment: I'm able to search my application on Playstore now, just uploaded the new APK and got it searched after day.